# How can I get the name of a GraphicsDevice

Tags: java

I have a list that needs to get all the video displays and add them all, however I need to add them as a label and get the name of it, but I do not see any String in GraphicsDevice that would return the name.

```
GraphicsDevice[] list = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();

        if (list != null) {
            if (list.length >= 1) {
                for (GraphicsDevice device : list) {
                    observableList.add(new Label(DEVICE NAME HERE));
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GraphicsDevice.getIDstring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getIDstring--) method provides such a String. Usage:

```
observableList.add(new Label(device.getIDstring()));
```